# Context inside Promise.resolve() / Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, promise

Im currently trying to use a Promise to resolve fetching models from database. In the following was:

```
Promise.resolve(app.Departments.fetch()).then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
    this.$el.html( this.template( {depts: app.Departments.toJSON()} ));
    this.$form = this.$('#form-employee');
    this.$form.validator();
    return this;
})
```

Consider everything is inside the **render** method and the method is inside a **Backbone.View.extend({})** object. The problem is that inside the Promise.resolve() function the context of this is different from the context inside the View object which it throws an error not knowing what does this refers to. Is there anyway to pass to Promise.resolve the correct context of **this**?

Comment: Notice you are calling `then` with a callback, not `resolve`.

Comment: Can you enlighten on this topic? I know then can be both used when resolving and rejecting stages of Promises.

Comment: The `then` method works on any promises regardless of their state. What my comment tried to emphasise that your problem stems from how `then` handles the callback, and has nothing to do where the promise comes from - be it `Promise.resolve` or anything else

Comment: Can you show an example of it? Is there any question you can refer me too.?

Comment: The correct usage of then. I would appreciate it.

Comment: You are already using it correctly? The callback is to blame here. See the linked duplicate for examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a local reference for this:

```
var self=this;
Promise.resolve(app.Departments.fetch()).then(function(response){
   console.log(response);
   self.$el.html( self.template( {depts: app.Departments.toJSON()} ));
   self.$form = this.$('#form-employee');
   self.$form.validator();
   return self;
})
```